# Who manage Amazon Web Service Ubuntu Server Images? - Seoul region

Tags: server, 16.04, amazon-ec2

I'm using Amazon Web Service and I'm operating my web server for my little blog.
I'm using Ubuntu server 14.04 LTS(Trusty Tahr) and It makes me very happy because of powerful performance.

I heard there is new released LTS server version, 16.04 LTS(Xenial Xerus).
Actually I'm not urgent because Ubuntu 14.04 LTS is also quite nice version of Ubuntu sever, but I just hope I want to use new image of Ubuntu.

So I googled some information and I [found that](https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/query/xenial/server/released.current.txt) I can use Ubuntu Server 16.04 for Amazon Web Service(made in AMI), but my region(ap-northeast-2, yes it's Asia/Pacific Region 2 -- Seoul Region) still can't get images of Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS on Community AMIs.

I want to know who manage this AWS Ubuntu Server images, and so I want to know release date of Seoul region's Ubuntu Server images (if I can) :)

Answer (score 0):

I copied ami-a7428ac6 from ap-northeast-1 and it seems to run fine in ap-northeast-2.

I suspect it's reaching cross-region for the apt repository updates, but I'm not personally worried about a little extra traffic during the setup stage.